# Adding a common header file to all existing source and header through Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

In Eclipse IDE(C++), how can I add a common header file to all existing source and header files? I have a common header file created say "common.h". This file needs to be included in all the source files (.c) as well all the header files (.h). Rather than manually adding #include "header.h", how can I do it through Eclipse in one go? My header "header.h" has

```
    #ifndef HEADER_H 
    #define HEADER_H 
    ....
    #endif
```

I am basically looking for a short cut to avoid the manual task.
In fact, this is part of a voluminous exercise where I would like to replace all std:;cout with myout (say) where myout is an object of my own class MYIOSTREAM subclassed from iostream and common.h is the header containing that class declaration. Possible other that manually opening each of the files and ...

Comment: You could likely hammer out a console app or shell script that could do it in a reasonably short amount of time.

Comment: I am surprised nobody asked: **why** ? Since your application likely compiles right now, it certainly is unnecessary to add this header. So why would you need that ?